# What is this git relay concept called?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I dont know the terms needed to google the way I want to solve my problem

Basically I want my git repo site's (github,gitlab,etc....) fancy issue tracking and other metrics, but I also want to run server side checks on code committed.

My initial idea is that I just setup a git server somewhere then somehow link my repo site to the server(this is the bit I dont know how to google). When I successfully  commit to my gitserver the changes will also be duplicated on the fancy git repo site.

Comment: Also note that you can set server hooks on most git web platforms. Might be worth checking if it can achieve whatever pre-receive tasks you need to perform on code.

Comment: Gitlab and Github support webhooks. These hooks can be invoked by interested events like `push` or `approve merger request/pull request`. If you use other hosting services, they should also have such hooks. Some also support Git's own hooks. You may need some program like Jenkins and its plugins to implement the task.

Comment: GitHub and GitLab support Actions (GitHub) and CI (GitLab). You can define pipelines to run on the server and perform checks. Or do you want to reject pushes if the checks fail?

Comment: @knittl Yea ideally i want to reject pushes/commits if checks fail.